# Parallax and scale effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

I would like to make a hover on each image with a zoom effect (ex : http://maisonullens.com/collections/ss16) but I use a parallax effect with this jquery script: https://github.com/nk-o/jarallax

How can I do a zoom effect with this script, how I can do?

**https://jsfiddle.net/uo34ru7d/25/**

Someone has successfully solved my problem, but with an other plugin :
I would like to make this with Jarallax.

[Hover with Parallax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41188427/hover-with-parallax)

```
div {
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
  background-image:url("http://hdwallpaperbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/background-pictures-2.jpg");
  margin:50px;
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;

}
```

.

```
$('div').jarallax({

  // parallax effect speed. 0.0 - 1.0
  speed             : 0.8,

  // path to your parallax image
  imgSrc            : null,

  // width & height of your parallax image
  imgWidth          : null,
  imgHeight         : null,

  // enable transformations for effect if supported. 
  enableTransform   : true,

  // z-index of parallax container.
  zIndex            : null

});

$("div").hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity":"0.5"});
    }, function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity":"1"});

});
```